# how to show facebook Events in application

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to show users event page in my app

i tried with graph api but not helps.

[image]

I want something like This

Comment: Write the code you tried.

Comment: `12345?fields=events` work without a problem. What have you tried? Are you missing the `user_events` permission?

Comment: NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/events"];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]; i tried only this much...

Comment: Without requesting the permission, you won't have any luck.

Comment: how? i mean with permission do i need to open session?

Comment: I'm no iOS developer but if you rephrase your question with this problem and tag it properly I'm sure someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Got Answer:

i did:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/events/list"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

its done

Thanks to all who tried to help me.

this will shows users events who had  loggedin - in device